# How to smooth line chart in javafx?

Tags: javafx, charts, line, smoothing

I want to implement the curved line chart in javafx. There should be curves instead of line to join all the points in line chart.Is there any  method to do that?

Comment: Have a look at http://fxexperience.com/2012/01/curve-fitting-and-styling-areachart/

Comment: yes..but I got some sharp edges while giving some points..

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. But you can override e. g. the XYChart and implement our own methods. It's not that hard to do, e. g. I implemented a [Gantt chart here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975898/gantt-chart-from-scratch) which shows you how to implement your own chart.